# Strange information on SauceLabs and test do not work correctly

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

run tests on Firefox after that on Chrome. Test which run on FF works correctly. Test with the same code but another driver settings(for Chrome) do not work correctly. I have following info from Saucelab's Chrome:

[image: error from saucelabs]

I create driver by that way:

```
[SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            DesiredCapabilities capabillities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
            capabillities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows 8.1");
            capabillities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "36");

            capabillities.SetCapability("name", "R(...)");
            capabillities.SetCapability("username", "My username");
            capabillities.SetCapability("accessKey", "my acces key value");

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabillities);
            baseURL = "http://starting address without www";

        }
```

Test fails after one command. The page loaded and after that error that he can not find element. I have tried many posibilities to find elem(by id, css, xpath).

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you solve the problem, [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: Ok, I did not know that...;) One moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "www" is necessary before web address to correctly runs test in Chrome on Saucelabs.

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabillities);
            baseURL = "http://www.(...)";
```